# Troubleshooting 'network error' on Google API write and insert using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api, google-api-js-client

I've successfully implemented Google Sheet API to read my sheet. And I updated SCOPE in the sign-in routine for read and write. I tested write and insert using Google's Try It! feature in advance of copying Google's code, and those work fine. But the write and insert functions in my Javascript app both fail with 'network errors.' I feel like write and insert might have the same problem. Where can I start troubleshooting? If it helps, the message for insert is:

```
error: A network error occurred, and the request could not be completed.
(anonymous function) — gerfnitauthor.droppages.com:1226
(anonymous function) — cb=gapi.loaded_0:111:176
xs — cb=gapi.loaded_0:114:340
Wq — cb=gapi.loaded_0:114:189
uea — cb=gapi.loaded_0:114
Ap — cb=gapi.loaded_0:107:289
promiseReactionJob
```

My insert function, lightly modified from the sample Google API code:

```
function insert_data(newValues)
{
    var params =
    {
        spreadsheetId: '1XDRtcVmBRaolVcpSpLMt2tp7ixWr7UMwus4CH3jHf64',
        range: 'A1:S1',
        valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
        responseValueRenderOption: 'FORMATTED_VALUE',
        insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
    };
    var valueRangeBody =
    {
        "majorDimension": "ROWS",
        "range": 'A1:S1',
        "values":
        [
            [newValues]
        ]
    };
    var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(params, valueRangeBody);
    request.then(function(response)
    {
        var insertResult = response.result;
    }, function(reason)
    {
        console.error('error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
    });
}
```

Comment: `A network error occurred` - do you know have any more information about this, i.e. from the browser developer tools network tab perhaps?

Comment: Evidently, the format of my values in the write and insert calls was messed up. I accidentally wrote all of the vales as one concatenated string, which isn't what I want. And I'm struggling to format the VALUES parameter of the write and insert calls. It errors out when I pass it an array with one array inside. I'll post that as a different question. Thanks for responding.

Comment: You can test request bodies in the Google APIs Explorer btw

Comment: In fact, that's how I figured out that the VALUES must be an array inside an array. The documentation says that, but I must have had a brain freeze because no matter how I specified it, I kept passing single values. A simple VALUES[0] = myValueArray; solved the problem. Thank you for reenforcing use of that feature.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what the 'network errors' were, but that doesn't matter because IT WORKS! I can write individual rows, insert new rows and even perform partial row updates using null padding. Impossible when you start out, simple once you've done it. Thanks to all for feedback/comments.